# ProgressDialog doesn't appear inside OnPreExecute

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I'm trying to create `ProgressDialog` during parsing of JSON objects. So I'm using `AsyncTask`:

```
    private class JsonUtility extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    //getting activity context like that since outer activity is not enclosing
    public JsonUtility(Activity activity){
        super();
        mActivity = activity;

    }

    public JsonUtility(){}

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

//...operate with JSON

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        dialog.hide();
    }
}
```

and I'm getting information from JSON like that:

```
    public ArrayList<CoursesData> getCourses(Activity activity){
    ArrayList<CoursesData> resultArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(new JsonUtility(activity).execute(coursesUrl).get());
//...and so on
}
```

activity is passed to `JsonUtility` when Fragment is created with `getActivity()`:

```
ArrayList<CoursesData> coursesDatas = parserJson.getCourses(getActivity());
```

**is it correct way to pass activity context from Fragment?**

Or probably problem lies somewhere else? This `ProgressDialog` simply doesn't appear although the loading takes about 2-3 sec.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Anyone? Any hint or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change mActivity to getParent()... its working for me

Comment: it crashes on that line with `NullPointerException` now.

Comment: yea, that returns activity. It crashes after `getParent()` is called

Comment: dialog = ProgressDialog.show(**mActivity**, "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);i found that rest code is ok except above line.. so try to give proper context related to your app.

Comment: That's actually the problem I'm trying to solve initially :D   thats why I posted this question since I belive context is passing wrong